# Como convertir a Integer getSelectedItem() de un JComboBox en Java

Tags: java

He intentado con lo siguiente pero no me compila el código:

```
Integer seleccion = (Integer)jcombo.getSelectedItem();
```

También con:

```
Integer seleccion = Integer.parseInt(jcombo.getSelectedItem());
```

y con:

```
Integer seleccion = Integer.valueOf(jcombo.getSelectedItem());
```

Les agradecería su ayuda!

Comment: Si solo necesitas el texto que se muestra al seleccionar un elemento en el JComboBox y no el objeto completo, es más sencillo obtenerlo con el método s = (String)jCombo.getSelectedItem(); Antes, revisa con qué lo cargas para asegurarte que siempre va a tener un valor

Answer (score 2):

El metodo jcombo.getSelectedItem() devuelve Object y no podras recuperar su valor de este modo entiendo que lo que necesitas es obtener el valor del ID seleccionado.
Puedes lograrlo con unas funciones ,Primero Creamos una clase que administrara las cargas de cualquier combox que deseemos.

```
    package Genericos;

   import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
   import java.sql.ResultSet;
   import java.sql.SQLException;
   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.logging.Level;
   import java.util.logging.Logger;

  public class PrepararDatosCombos {
  private ResultSet rs;
  private PreparedStatement ps;
  private ArrayList<comboItem> lista;
  private comboItem item;

 /*
Realizamos un select de tipo id,descripcion solo dos columnas
cargamos el array.
*/
public PrepararDatosCombos(String query) {
    try {
        ConexionDB.getInstancia();
        ps=ConexionDB.getDBcon().prepareStatement(query);
        rs=ps.executeQuery();
        lista=new ArrayList<>();
        while (rs.next()) {                
          //nuevo objeto
          item=new comboItem();
          item.setId(rs.getInt(1));
          item.setDescrip(rs.getString(2));
          //agregando el objeto a la lista
          lista.add(item);
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
               Logger.getLogger(PrepararDatosCombos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

/*
Retorna El array con los valores del Select
*/
public ArrayList<comboItem> getItemsCombo(){
    return lista;
}

/*
Retorna el id del Elemento seleccionado en el combox mediante su Posicion
*/
public Integer getIdSegunIndice(Integer indice){

return (indice >= 0 ? lista.get(indice).getId() : 0);

}

/*
Nuestra clase para El ArrayList
*/
public class comboItem{
    private Integer id;
    private String descrip;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDescrip() {
        return descrip;
    }

      public void setDescrip(String descrip) {
        this.descrip = descrip;
      }
   }
 }
```

Ahora en la clase que queremos utilizarlo realizamos lo siguiente.
metodo para cargar el combox.
Declaramos a nivel de clase.

```
private PrepararDatosCombos Preparador;



public void cargarComboUbicaccion() {
    //perfiles
    Sql ="SELECT id_ubi, descripcion FROM ubic_producto ORDER BY id_ubi;";
    Preparador = new PrepararDatosCombos(Sql);
    stock.comboUbicacion.removeAllItems();
    for (PrepararDatosCombos.comboItem item : Preparador.getItemsCombo()) {
        comboUbicacion.addItem(item.getDescrip());
    }
}
```

Luego el metodo que recuperara el id del item seleccionado en el Combox.

```
public int  getIDUbicaccion() { 
   return Preparador.getIdSegunIndice(comboUbicacion.getSelectedIndex());    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Dado que el elemento puede ser `null`, para evitar un NPE, haz esto:

```
Integer i = (Integer)jcombo.getSelectedItem();
if (i != null) {
    int seleccion = i; 
}else{
    int seleccion = 0; //Por si necesitas disponer a toda costa de una variable seleccion para evaluar algo
}
```

Comment: De hecho el resultado es null. Necesito convertir el getSelectedItem() para pasarlo como parámetro a un método!

Comment: Si es null lo que tienes que revisar entonces es cómo se está llenando tu combobox

Comment: Esto tiene un problema. seleccion no es visible desde fuera del if-else. Mucho mejor y mas simple definirlo como 0 al principio y hacer solo un if para asignarlo.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías probar con :

```
try {
     int numero  = Integer.parseInt(combo.getSelectedItem().toString());
}catch(NumberFormatException e ){
     //Capturas la excepcion si el elemento del combo no es un numero.
     System.out.println("El elemento seleccionado no es un numero");
}
```

La unica diferencia con la respuesta de A.Cedano es que en mi caso yo no utilizo la clase Integer , si no simplemente "int", quizas es eso por lo que no te funciona correctamente.Espero que te sirva mi respuesta.

Answer (score -1):

En ese caso lo único que tiene que hacer es lo siguente:

```java
Integer seleccion = Integer.parseInt((String)jcombo.getSelectedItem());
```